# NGX-translate: extend translations without overriding existing ones

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

In ngx-translate, is it possible, when adding a new translation, that the original translation has the priority during the merge?

In other words: when a key is defined already, the original value should be kept and not replaced.

My use case is to load libs in a monorepo with their own translation-files. The lib translations should be defaults, but the translations defined in the app (and loaded originally), should have a higher priority and override those in the libs.

when calling setTranslation with shouldMerge = true, the new translation always replaces the old one.